# Bootstrap, Rubin's rules, and uncertainty of sub-estimates?

Tags: variance, bootstrap, missing-data, multiple-imputation, resampling

Can someone provide an intuition for why, when using bootstrap to calculate the variability of an estimate (say a regression coefficient $\beta$) we don't need to incorporate the uncertainty of each bootstrapped estimate ($\hat\beta_i$)?

On the other hand, why is it that when using Rubin's rules we *do* need to incorporate the uncertainty of the parameter estimate on each imputed dataset?

What is the intuition for this difference between these procedures?

(Edit:) In other words, why is the uncertainty of the MI sub-estimates an underestimate of the uncertainty of the  MI estimate? Also, what would happen if we tried to incorporate the uncertainty of the bootstrap sub-estimates (e.g. in linear regression, by sampling from each $\beta_i$ t-distribution) into the bootstrap procedure? Would it change anything?

Comment: Multiple Imputation is a Bayesian procedure, while bootstrapping is (typically) frequentist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a fairly long answer, there is a summary at the end)

The theoretical justifications given below, based mainly on [this](https://faculty.washington.edu/azhou/teaching/biost578-2007/prosper_template1-25-07.pdf), [this](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture13.pdf), [this](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Law_of_total_variance.html), [this](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter8.pdf), and [this](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation.html) articles, can help you get the intuition you are after. Otherwise, let me know.

**I. The theoretical justification on MI is large sample bayesian approximation, as follows:**

1. Using iterative procedures, we create draws from the posterior distribution of $θ$ (or $\beta$ to keep with your notation).
2. In that case, a large number of draws $D$ are needed.
3. If we assume normality of the observed-data posterior distribution, we need to estimate only the mean and variance–much less $D$ are needed.
4. In that case, a very limited $D$ are required to estimate reliably the distribution mean.
5. MI is based on this idea.
6. If we assume $p(θ | y_{obs})$ is approximately normal, the observed-data posterior can be effectively determined by the posterior mean and variance, $ E(θ | y_{obs})$ and $Var(θ | Y_{obs}) $
7. Note that $E(θ | y_{obs}) = E[E(θ | y_{mis}, y_{obs}) | Y_{obs}] =
   \int E(θ | y_{mis}, y_{obs})p(y_{mis} | y_{obs})dy_{mis}$

where the outer expectation is taken with respect to the
posterior predictive distribution, $p(y_{mis} | y_{obs})$

8. And that,
   $Var(θ | Y_{obs}) = E[Var(θ | Y_{mis}, Y_{obs}) | Y_{obs}]+
   Var[E(θ | Y_{mis}, Y_{obs}) | Y_{obs}]$

where the outer expectation is taken with respect to the
posterior predictive distribution, $p(y_{mis} | y_{obs})$

9. In that case, $E[Var(θ | Y_{mis}, Y_{obs}) | Y_{obs}] =
   \int Var(θ | Y_{mis}, Y_{obs})p(Y_{mis} | Y_{obs})dY_{mis}$ and,

$Var[E(θ | Y_{mis}, Y_{obs}) | Y_{obs}] = \int E^2(θ | Y_{mis}, Y_{obs})p(Y_{mis} | Y_{obs})dY_{mis}−(\int  E(θ | Y_{mis}, Y_{obs})p(Y_{mis} | Y_{obs}))^2$

10. For large $D$,

$E[E(θ| Y_{mis}, Y_{obs})|Y_{obs}] \approx \frac{1}{D} \sum_{d=1}^D \widehat θ_d$

$E[Var(θ|Y_{mis}^{(d)},y_{obs}) \approx 
\bar V = \frac{1}{D} \sum_{d=1}^D Var(θ|Y_{mis}^{(d)},y_{obs})$

$Var[E(θ|y_{mis}, y_{obs})|y_{obs}] \approx 
B = \frac{1}{D - 1}\sum_{d=1}^D (\widehat θ - \bar θ)^2$

where,

$Y_{mis}^{(d)}$ are independent draws of $Y_{mis} $ from the posterior
predictive distribution $p(y_{mis} | y_{obs})$, $\widehat θ_d = E(θ|Y_{mis}^{(d)},y_{obs})$ the complete-data posterior mean of $θ$ calculated for the $d$th imputed data set $(Y_{mis}^{(d)}, Y_{obs})$, 
$Var(θ|Y_{mis}^{(d)},y_{obs})$ the complete-data posterior
variance of $θ$ calculated for the calculated for the $d$th imputed data set $(Y_{mis}^{(d)}, Y_{obs})$

and,

$\bar θ = \frac{1}{D}\sum_{d=1}^D (\widehat θ)$

$\bar V$: within-imputation variance

$B$: between-imputation variance

Therefore:

> Total variance $T$ can be estimated using $T = \bar V + (1 + D^{-1})B$
>
> and approximated using $T \approx \bar V + B$
>
> while MI point estimate for $E(θ|y_{obs}$), (that is, for $θ$) is obtained using $\bar θ = \frac{1}{D}\sum_{d=1}^D (\widehat θ)$

**II. A bootstrap algorithm for estimating the variance of $θ_n$ (or $\beta$ to keep with your notation) and for constructing confidence intervals works as follows:**

1. We would like to find the variance of $θ_n$. 
   Let, $Var_P(θ_n) = Var_P (g(X1, . . . , X_n)) ≡ S_n(P)$
2. Note that $Var_P (θ_n)$ is some function of *P* (and *n*) so I have written $Var_P(θ_n) = S_n(P)$

If we knew $P$, we could approximate $ S_n(P)$ by simulation as follows:

(a) draw $X1, . . . , X_n ∼ P$

(b) compute $\widehat θ_n^{(1)} = g(X1, . . . , X_n)$

(c) draw $X1, . . . , X_n ∼ P$

(d) compute $\widehat θ_n^{(2)} = g(X1, . . . , X_n)$

(e) draw $X_1, . . . , X_n ∼ P$

(f) compute $\widehat θ_n^{(B)} = g(X1, . . . , Xn)$

Let $s^2$ be the sample variance of $\widehat θ_n^{(1)} , . . . , \widehat θ_n^{(B)} $

So $s^2 = \frac{1}{B} \sum_{i=1}^B (\widehat θ)^2 - (\frac{1}{B} \sum_{i=1}^B \widehat θ)^2$

By the law of large numbers, $s^2 \rightarrow E[(\widehat θ)^2] - (E[(\widehat θ)])^2 = Var(\widehat θ) = S_n(P)$

Since we can take $B$ as large as we want, we have that $s^2 \approx Var_P(\widehat θ_n)$

In other words, we can approximate $S_n(P)$ by repeatedly simulating $n$ observations from $P$.

But we don’t know $P$. So we estimate $S_n(P)$ with $S_n(P_n)$ where $P_n$ is the empirical distribution. Since $P_n$ is a consistent estimator, we expect that $S_n(P_n) ≈ S_n(P)$

In other words:

Bootstrap approximation of the variance: estimate $S_n(P)$ with $S_n(P_n)$

Or in other words $\widehat {Var_P(θ_n)} = Var_{Pn}(\widehat θ_n)$

Question: But how do we compute $S_n(P_n)$

Answer: We use the simulation method above, except that we simulate
from $P_n$ instead of $P$. This leads to the following algorithm:

> Bootstrap Variance Estimator:

(a) Draw a bootstrap sample $X_1^*, ..., X_n^*$

(b) Compute $ \widehat θ_n^* = g(X_1^*, ..., X_n^*)$

(c) Repeat the previous step B times, yielding estimator $ \widehat θ_{n,1}^*, ..., \widehat θ_{n,B}^*$

(d) Compute:

$\widehat s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{B} \sum_{j=1}^B (\widehat θ_{n,1}^* - \bar θ)^2}$

where $\barθ = \frac{1}{B} \sum_{j=1}^B \widehat θ_{n,j}^*$

(e) Output $\widehat s$

Therefore, you can think about it like this:
$\frac{1}{B} \sum_{j=1}^B (\widehat θ_{n,1}^* - \bar θ)^2 \approx S_n(P_n) \approx
S_n(P) $

These last two approximations are our two sources of error in this
estimation of variance. The first is due to the fact that n is finite
and the second is due to the fact that B is finite. However, we can
make B as large as we like. (In practice, it usually suffices to take
B = 10, 000.) So we ignore the error due to finite B.

> **Summary:**
>
> **Question 1: Why is the uncertainty of the MI sub-estimates an
>   underestimate of the uncertainty of the MI estimate?**
>
> Answer: Because of the law of total variance as illustrated in step
>   I.8 above, $Var(θ | Y_{obs}) = E[Var(θ | Y_{mis}, Y_{obs}) |
>  Y_{obs}]+ Var[E(θ | Y_{mis}, Y_{obs}) | Y_{obs}]$. Otherwise, you will
>   be violating this law. See article [3](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Law_of_total_variance.html) for more details about the
>   justification of the law of total variance. However, if you do $D$ multiple imputations to get $D$ datasets, and then you generate $B$ bootstrap samples from each of the $D$ imputed datasets yielding $D * B$ datasets $D_{d,b}^*$, and if in each of these datasets the quantity of interest is estimated, that is, $ \widehat θ_{d,b}^*$. Then, the pooled sample of the ordered estimates $θ_{MIBP}^* = \{\widehat θ_{d,b}^*; b = 1, ..., B; d = 1, ..., D\}$  can be used to construct a correct confidence interval for $θ$ by using $[\widehat θ_{lower}, \widehat θ_{upper}]_{MIBP} = [\widehat θ_{MIBP}^{*, \alpha} \widehat θ_{MIBP}^{*,1 - \alpha}]$, instead of the law of total variance, where $\widehat θ_{MIBP}^{*, \alpha}$ is the $\alpha$-percentile of the ordered bootstrap estimates $θ_{MIBP}^*$. For more details see article [6](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.7654).
>
> **Question 2: What would happen if we tried to incorporate the
>   uncertainty of the bootstrap sub-estimates (e.g. in linear regression,
>   by sampling from each  t-distribution) into the bootstrap
>   procedure? Would it change anything?**
>
> Answer: Because of the law of large numbers as illustrated in step II.2.f) above, $s^2 \rightarrow
> E[(\widehat θ)^2] - (E[(\widehat θ)])^2 = Var(\widehat θ) = S_n(P)$ is
>   a valid approximation of the true variance. Therefore, doing what you
>   are suggesting would simply add unnecessary noise to the variance. See
>   article [4](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter8.pdf) for more details about the justification of the law of
>   large numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Krantz, but I don't really get the answer to my question from this. I edited it to add some specific questions that maybe you can answer that I think will help.

Comment: Hi, @user242413. Just edited the answer. Let me know if the updated summary helps you expand your intuition.